# OrientDB No edge created Execption

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am currently getting a "No edge created" exception while using OrientDB 2.1

As per the CREATE EDGE documentation (http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Create-Edge.html):

> Beginning with version 2.1, when no edges are created OrientDB throws
>   a OCommandExecutionException error. This makes it easier to integrate
>   edge creation in transactions. In such cases, if the source or target
>   vertices don't exist, it rolls back the transaction.

I was wondering if there was some way to log/print out information regarding the vertices it is trying to create an edge between. I am using a JSON file to query for updates from a DB and transformer inside that JSON to create the edges using the IDs as parameters of the query results. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue of getting ID information of the vertices by adding "log": "debug" to the JSON file.